# What's a protein pulldown assay?

Tags: molecular-biology

I'm reading a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1931312811004033) and the authors mention a "protein pulldown" assay.

I've never done this before, and googling doesn't bring up much. Could I get a rundown of the basic theory behind it?

Also does % coverage have anything to do with this assay?

Answer (score 6):

Pull down mostly refers to immunoprecipitation, however pulling down can be done using other interactions such as streptavidin-biotin or His-tag-Nickel.

In a protein pull-down a protein is enriched along with the molecules bound to it. When the DNA that is bound to a protein is studied, the experiment is called ChIP (Chromatin ImmunoPrecipitation). When other proteins that are bound to a given protein are studied then the experiment is called Co-IP. 
Similarly RNA bound to protein can also be studied.

It is also possible to pull-down an RNA or a DNA fragment using complementary oligonucleotide, streptavidin, antibodies etc and study their interacting partners.

In the linked paper, they have immunoprecipitated a HA (haemagglutinin) tagged protein using an anti-HA-tag antibody (Note that this is just a small tag of 9-10 amino acids and not the entire HA protein. Such tags are useful when you don't have the antibody for a given protein).

They have done both co-IP and ChIP:

> HA-tagged, full-length PfSET10 protein and interacting proteins from
>   3D7/PfSET10HA and control line 3D7 were purified using anti-HA beads

> Chromatin Immunoprecipitation (ChIP) and Transcriptional Profiling
>
> ChIP analysis was performed as described (Flueck et al., 2009).

Coverage is a term used in sequencing experiments which usually refers to average number of reads that map to any locus; this is also called **depth**. This is commonly used in RNA/DNA sequencing studies (See [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8048/results-of-a-complete-dna-sequencing-are-they-100-reusable/8050#8050) post too). In this paper, as mentioned in the other answer, the term coverage is used for peptide reads (analyzed by mass spectrometry) and it is the **horizontal coverage** not a vertical coverage. Horizontal coverage refers to the fraction of actual molecule (DNA/RNA/protein) covered by the assembly of reads.

Coverage has got nothing to do with the pull-down assay; it is used in the context of the downstream experiment.

Answer (score 2):

From [Life Technologies](http://www.lifetechnologies.com/us/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/pull-down-assays.html)

> The pull-down assay is an in vitro method used to determine a physical interaction between two or more proteins. Pull-down assays are useful for both confirming the existence of a protein-protein interaction predicted by other research techniques (e.g., co-immunoprecipitation) and as an initial screening assay for identifying previously unknown protein-protein interactions.

It is essentially the same as an [immunoprecipitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunoprecipitation) experiment but using proteins instead of antibodies.

Coverage comes into play for identifying the pulled-down proteins as they used an [LC-MS/MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_chromatography%E2%80%93mass_spectrometry) analysis. You essentially have to map back the short peptide reads you get from the MS to the actual pulled-down proteins which gives you a coverage score, i.e. how much of the full protein sequence you covered with short peptides.